# NullPointerException, what is causing my error?

Tags: java, android, xml, error-handling, nullpointerexception

Logcat is returning me a nullPointerException on line 42 in Records.java. Line 42 says "daily_record.setText(Daily_Record_Option);" Can you guys just glance over this code? I have been trying to solve this for a few hours now, and nothing I have tried has helped. Thanks!
**Records.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class Records extends MainActivity {

public int default_int_day = 0;
public int default_int_week = 0;
static boolean daily_recieved = false;
static boolean weekly_recieved = false;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    TextView daily_record = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.daily_textview);
    TextView weekly_record = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weekly_textview);



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.personal_records);

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    int Daily_Record_Option = sharedPrefs.getInt("daily", counter);
    int Weekly_Record_Option = sharedPrefs.getInt("weekly", counter_weekly);
    if(isSavedDaily){
        if(Daily_Record_Option > default_int_day){
            daily_record.setText(Daily_Record_Option);
            default_int_day = Daily_Record_Option;
            daily_recieved = true;
        }else if(default_int_day > Daily_Record_Option){
            daily_record.setText(default_int_day);
            daily_recieved = false;
        }else{
            daily_record.setText("No records yet!");
        }

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "No daily data saved yet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
      if(isSavedWeekly){
          if(Weekly_Record_Option > default_int_week){
              weekly_record.setText(Weekly_Record_Option);
              default_int_week = Weekly_Record_Option;
              weekly_recieved = true;
          } else if(default_int_week > Weekly_Record_Option){
              weekly_record.setText(default_int_week);
              weekly_recieved = false;
          }

      }else{
          Toast.makeText(this, "No  weekly data saved yet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      }








}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.records_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.Back){
        Intent records_intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(records_intent);

        return true;

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

And the layout file:
**personal_records.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FF8B00"
android:id="@+id/Personal_Records">

<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:text="@string/Your_Records"
android:id="@+id/textView5"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_margin="40dp"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:text="@string/Weekly_Record"
android:id="@+id/textView6"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView5"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/weekly_textview"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView6"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:text="\@null"/>
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:text="@string/Daily_Record"
android:id="@+id/textView7"
android:layout_below="@+id/weekly_textview"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView5"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
android:paddingTop="20dp"/>

<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/daily_textview"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView6"
android:text="\@null"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</RelativeLayout
```

And the logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at haveabeer.two.padc.haveabeer.Records.onCreate(Records.java:43)
//Here ^^^
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
```

LINE 43 Says: "daily_record.setText(Daily_Record_Option);"
It is line 43 now because I moved some stuff around up top. But the area the error is being thrown is in/around the same area.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.ImageButton;

import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
public int counter = 0;
public int counter_weekly = 0;
Calendar daily_calender = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = daily_calender.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int second = daily_calender.get(Calendar.SECOND);
int minute = daily_calender.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int day = daily_calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
public boolean isSavedDaily = true;
public boolean isSavedWeekly = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageButton beer = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Data",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    counter = sharedPrefs.getInt("daily", counter);
    counter_weekly = sharedPrefs.getInt("weekly", counter_weekly);
    TextView beer_count_onLoad = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    beer_count_onLoad.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.beerCount) + "" + counter);
    TextView beer_week_count_onLoad = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    beer_week_count_onLoad.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.beerWeek) + "" +     counter_weekly);
    final TextView beer_count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    final TextView beer_week = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);


    beer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter++;
            counter_weekly++;
            beer_count.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.beerCount) + "" + counter );
            beer_week.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.beerWeek) + "" + counter_weekly );


        }
    });

    ResetVariablesTimers();


}


private void ResetVariablesTimers() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Data",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    if(hour == 0 && second == 0 && minute == 0 ){
        TextView reset_notification = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        reset_notification.setText("Daily was reset to 0, was at 400");
        editor.putInt("daily", counter);

        editor.commit();
        isSavedDaily=true;

        ResetVariables();





    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Not time of the day yet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        isSavedDaily=true;

        if(day == 2 && second == 0 && minute == 0 && hour == 0 ){
            TextView reset_notification_weekly = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            reset_notification_weekly.setText("Weekly was reset to 0, was at 400");
            editor.putInt("weekly", counter_weekly);
            editor.commit();
            isSavedWeekly=true;
            ResetVariables();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not time of the month yet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            isSavedWeekly=false;
        }


    }}

public void ResetVariables() {
    if(Records.daily_recieved = true){
        counter = 0;
    }
    if(Records.weekly_recieved = true){
        counter_weekly = 0;
    }


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("daily", counter);
    editor.putInt("weekly", counter_weekly);
    editor.commit();
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }else if (id == R.id.Personal_Records && isSavedDaily){

        Intent records_intent = new Intent(this, Records.class);
        startActivity(records_intent);

        return true;

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "No records available yet!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("daily", counter);
    editor.putInt("weekly", counter_weekly);
    editor.commit();
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("daily_counter", counter);
    outState.putInt("weekly_counter", counter_weekly);
    ResetVariablesTimers();

}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    counter = savedInstanceState.getInt("daily_counter");
    counter_weekly = savedInstanceState.getInt("weekly_counter");
    TextView daily = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    daily.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.beerCount) + counter);
    TextView weekly = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    weekly.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.beerWeek) + counter);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("daily", counter);
    editor.putInt("weekly", counter_weekly);
    editor.commit();
    super.onDestroy();
    ResetVariablesTimers();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("daily", counter);
    editor.putInt("weekly", counter_weekly);
    editor.commit();
    ResetVariablesTimers();

    super.onStop();
}
}
```

Can you also give your ideas on how I can make ResetVariableTimers() better? What I am trying to do with this is reset the daily and weekly counters when a new day/week rolls around. I was thinking that this should probably be a background service, but I don't know where to go with that.

Comment: Try changing line `daily_record.setText(Daily_Record_Option);` with `daily_record.setText(Daily_Record_Option + "");`

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Nope, that didn't work.

Comment: You are extending `MainActivity`; may be something is wrong there. This class doesn't seem to have any error except you should not use integer in `setText` method like you are doing. Using integer in `setText` has completely different meaning.

Comment: I removed extends MainActivity and there were errors everywhere. So to fix this I obviously pushed ALT+ENTER to see what Android Studio suggests, but that was of no help. In one of my other activities I used an int in a setText and it worked perfectly. So I have absolutely no clue what there is left to try.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Do you think that the problem could stem from the fact that the Records.java activity is started when the user clicks on the ActionBar item in the upper right hand corner called "Your Records"? Is that a fragment?

Comment: No I don't think so. If you could send me your code I could see what wrong there.

Comment: Ok Ill add My MainActivity.java in the post above

Comment: @Rohit5k2 I added MainActivity.java. I also added a few lines of text to the bottom containing another question I had.

Comment: Extending activities like this might be creating issue. Use fragment for Record instead. Main activity has its views. When Record is calling super.onCreate() this might be creating problem. Either move code of Main activity in Record (only that is being used in this) or use a fragment.

Comment: Maybe @CommonsWare can help us with this situation. CommonsWare, any ideas?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 does my SharedPreferences stuff look ok in MainActivity? And do you think my timer in ResetVariablesTimers() will work? I believe they will only work when the app is running. onDestroy() the timers will stop and not serve their purpose if a day/week passes while the app is destroyed. Sound right?

Comment: Yeah, u need a service for that.

Comment: Ah oh, I have alot of reworking to do. Thanks for your help @Rohit5k2

Comment: Sorry to say but yes you do. Please don't extend activities like this. It would again cause problems.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to get your `TextView` without setting the content in the activity.

Put these lines after `setContentView(R.layout.personal_records);`

```
TextView daily_record = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.daily_textview);
TextView weekly_record = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weekly_textview);
```

Also, You shouldn't use integer in `setText`; It has completely different meaning. If you do so it would look for a resource with that integer value.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to inflate your view before you reference any elements from it. At the time you have these two lines of code,

```
TextView daily_record = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.daily_textview);
TextView weekly_record = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weekly_textview);
```

your view is still null and hence the NullPointer Exception. You should first call setContentView(R.layout.myView) before you reference any elements.

Comment: I just did it and I still get nullPointerException.

Comment: You need to move `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.personal_records);` to right after `@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`

Comment: Can you let me know what line 42 corresponds to? And could you please post the stack trace.